# Blackberry "found an alternate icon with better size" error

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I can't get this error disappear even when I remove the Blackberry nature from the project. It was working well before. How can I resolve this error?
My Android version is 4.2.2.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
[ERROR] [appname.apk]:(res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png) found an alternate icon with better size:impact=1
```